# How to use entity reference field titles in Views exposed and combined filters

Tags: views, entities

I have two content types: Institution and Contact.

Any number of Contacts are associated with any number of Institutions.

Contacts are associated with Institutions via an Entity Reference field.

I have a view defined as follows:

Format: Show: Fields
Content: Published (Yes)
Content: Type = (Institution)
Content: Title (exposed)
Content: Contact (exposed)
Combined: Titles and Contacts (exposed)

The current sticking point is the exposed filter for Contact (an Entity Reference) requires the integer value of field_data_field_contact.field_contact_target_id, which frontend users have no means of knowing. I need a way of translating a Contact node's Title to the target ID transparently, and this method must also be accessible to the combined field Titles and Contacts.

Result sets for contacts are in the thousands, so providing a dropdown to the view is not workable.

The view type is likely set in stone, because it has been in production for years and has a great many fields.

Answer (score 0):

You just need use [Views Reference Filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter)